# Install nvidia-smi on OSX

Tags: macos, graphics, gpu

I tried installing nvidia-smi with home-brew, but it is not working out, this is my output

```
-bash: nvidia-smi: command not found
```

I have CUDA 7.5 installed and this is the output of my `nvcc -V` command

Mine is a 15" Macbook Pro Retina, with Nvidia 750M GPU

> nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
>   Copyright (c) 2005-2015 NVIDIA Corporation
>   Built on Thu_Sep_24_00:26:39_CDT_2015
>   Cuda compilation tools, release 7.5, V7.5.19

Output of kextstat command

```
    kextstat | grep -i cuda
  140    0 0xffffff7f82675000 0x2000     0x2000     com.nvidia.CUDA (1.1.0) 5AFE550D-6361-3897-912D-897C13FF6983 <4 1>
```

OS version 10.11.4

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  What do you mean by "it's not working out?"  What is it (not) doing?  Also, it's helpful if you provide your OS version.

Comment: In this case simply what is your PATH and in what directory does  Homebrew install nvidia-dmi - the issue is simply the file is not found by the shell i.e. only the first two lines are relevant

Answer (score 4):

In Macs there is no nvidia-smi command that comes with nvidia drivers. However, you could check this open-source alternative : https://github.com/phvu/cuda-smi

Edit in 2020 : 
As an alternative to nvidia-smi is Activity Monitor. Search on spotlight (cmd + space) and type Activity Monitor. When the program opens press cmd + 4. This will show you the active usage of GPU(s) on your system.
I think this feature comes with High Sierra 10.13 prior to that there is no option for gpu history.